# Why are Vertices of Plane createt by list of vertices are changing Position when the plane is rotated around the Z axis?

Tags: python

[image]

I have the following Problem. The planes you can see here are created with lists of vertices. If you rotate these Planes the vertices "jump" so to speak. I don't know why this is happening. Here is a snippet of my code :

```
with open(fp) as f:
 json_string = json.load(f)
 with open(lp) as l: 
     layer = json.load(l)
 with open(sp) as s: 
     static_passes = json.load(s)
 for i, row in enumerate(json_string):
    verts = [(row[0][0], row[0][1], 0), (row[1][0], row[1][1], 0), (row[2][0], row[2][1], 0), (row[3][0], row[3][1], 0)]
    faces = [(0,1,2,3)]
    edges = []
    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("Plane")
    object = bpy.data.objects.new("Plane", mesh)

    mesh.from_pydata(verts, edges, faces)
```

Comment: The problem is likely unrelated to your Python code. You have some planes in the background and probably snapping enabled.

Comment: Looks like a floating point precision problem. Are your coordinates very far from origin ?

Comment: @Gorgious yes they are far from the origin. I try to change that.

Comment: Simplest way to go in object mode : Right click > set origin > to geometry. Then ALT +G to reset the location